# Unable to install reactstrap from npm

Tags: reactjs, npm, bootstrap-4, npm-install, reactstrap

I am learning react and trying to use reactstrap for the first time. I have installed the react with npm with the following command and got the following result:

```
    npm install reactstrap
+ reactstrap@8.4.1
updated 1 package and audited 919281 packages in 10.948s

53 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 19 vulnerabilities (18 moderate, 1 high)
```

But I am getting the following error when I try to run the app:

[image]

Comment: You need quotes around reactstrap: `from 'reactstrap'` instead of `from reactstrap`.

Comment: Because remember to read the actual error: "Parsing error: Unexpected token" is telling you there's an unexpected token, e.g. you wrote something that doesn't make sense. Not that you wrote something that _does_ make sense and that the problem is that reactstrap is somehow unavailable.

Answer (score 0):

I had to reactstrap inside single quotes so instead of reactstrap I used 'reactstrap' and problem was solved.